# Как в wp_customize сделать «Добавить новое поле»?

Tags: wordpress

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как добавить нужному контролу опцию - "Добавить нужное поле"?

Answer (score 3):

Для того, чтобы добавить своё поле, вам нужно знать название секции. В примере ниже я добавляю поле "Телефон" в Секцию настроек "Свойства сайта". Надо открыть dev tools в браузере и навести на `<ul>`, который содержит открытую секцию. Вся секция будет покрыта фоном, а в id ul вы увидите требуемое название.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Из id (подчеркнуто красным) уберите `sub-accordion-section-` и вы узнаете искомое `title_tagline`. Теперь можно добавить код в `functions.php`

```
/**
 * Theme customizer: add phone.
 *
 * @param WP_Customize_Manager $wp_customize WP_Customize_Manager instance.
 */
function customize_register_action( $wp_customize ) {
    //All our sections, settings, and controls will be added here
    $a = $wp_customize;
    $wp_customize->add_setting(
            'title_tagline_phone',
            array(
                'default' => '+7 (777) 777-77-77',
            )
        );
    $wp_customize->add_control(
        'title_tagline_phone',
        array(
            'label'   => 'Телефон',
            'section' => 'title_tagline',
            'type'    => 'text',
        )
    );
}

add_action( 'customize_register', 'customize_register_action' );
```

Результат вы видите на картинке выше.

Comment: Вы меня немного не поняли.. мне нужно добавить функционал, например к вашей кнопке "Телефон" -  "Добавить новое полей", то есть, чтобы можно было дублировать нужное поле и выводить на страницу

Comment: ну так и продублируйте код. Или нарисуйте, чего вы хотите.

Comment: Если я не знаю, сколько будет скиллов один или пять? Вот нашел такую кнопку, которая добавляет динамически новое поле социальной сети, в коде полазил, особо ничего не разобрал.. много файлов подключается везде.. все запутанно.

Comment: А подскажите неучу как теперь вставить это поле чтобы его данные отображались на сайте? А то у меня ошибку выдает когда делаю так... <?php title_tagline_phone(); ?>